# How to post data to an API using Guzzle/HTTP client from a function

Tags: laravel

I have 2 web systems on development, system A and system B.in system An upon creating a product its stored in the products table and at the same time pushed to a same products table in system B.I am using GuzzleHttpClient() connect to API that posts the data to the system b.on die dump am getting the data that I have created in an array but the problem is the data isn't being pushed to the API that posts the data.instead am getting an error **Server error: `POST http://systemb/api/push_products` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response:**.I have understood where the error is coming from.the URL is being read in the HTTP client but the data isn't being pushed.

Here is my function that creates the data

```
$product_details=new Product;
$product_details->product_title=$request->product_title;
$product_details->product_details=$request->product_details;
$product_details->save();

// http client request to push data to systemb

$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$url = "http://systemb/api/push_products";

$input = $request->all();


//Post to server
$response = $client->request('POST',$url,[
    $input
]);
```

On die dump the $input I get an array of all the product details have created.

here is the api route

```
Route::post('/push_products','APIFcController@push_data')->name('localaccess.interface.pushdata');
```

This is my *push_data function* in the API

```
  protected $api_except_route = ['localaccess.interface.pushdata','localaccess.interface.licence'];

  public function __construct(){
    try {
    
        $routeName = request()->route()->getName();
    
        if (!in_array($routeName, $this->api_except_route)) {       
            if (empty(request()->header('X-API-KEY-FC')))
                throw new \Exception("Security key not found");

            if (!$this->auth_key(request()->header('X-API-KEY-FC')))
                throw new \Exception("Invalid security key");
        } else {
            $this->init_company     = DB::table('company')->first();
            $this->dest_location    = DB::table('location')->first();
        }

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->handleError($e);
    }
}

  public function push_data(Request $request)
  {
        $product_details=new Product;
        $product_details->product_title=$request->product_title;
        $product_details->product_details=$request->product_details;
        $product_details->save();
   }
```

on system b laravel log file am getting this errors

```
 2022-02-14 20:57:42] production.ERROR: No application encryption key has been specified. {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Encryption\\MissingAppKeyException(code: 0): No application encryption key has been specified. at F:\\systemb\\trunk\\systemb\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider.php:79)
```

[stacktrace]

I haven't understood why the data is not being pushed to the API.

Comment: Nothing useful in laravel's log file?

Comment: @brombeer i have viewed the log file and nothing that can assist to debug

Comment: @stephenwaweru99 still you should copy Log file for this Server Error. Please do so

Comment: There must be an error from your system B. See your Laravel log and perhaps server log if nothing is there on Laravel log.

Comment: @skyez i have updated some details in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code is perfect i had made a small syntax error in the env file